# Rows cannot be added programatically in Gridview. Index Error

Tags: c#, mysql

Hi i want to retrieve data from database to Gridview. I am using Custom Grid Here is the c# code

```
try
{
    int i=0;
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select accounts,credit,debit,sum(credit) as c,sum(debit) as d from tbl_open_balance", con);
    dr=cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while(dr.Read())
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value=dr["accounts"].ToString();
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = dr["credit"].ToString();
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = dr["debit"].ToString();
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        i++;
    }
    dataGridView1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
    dataGridView1.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(238,239,249);
    dataGridView1.CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.SingleHorizontal;
    dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.DarkTurquoise;
    dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
    dataGridView1.BackgroundColor = Color.White;

    dataGridView1.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
    dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersBorderStyle = DataGridViewHeaderBorderStyle.None;
    dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(20, 25, 72);
    dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
    dr.Close();

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    dr.Close();
}
```

I received the error Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Comment: Most likely because `int i=1` - indexes in programming begin from 0. But better still is for each record in the `rd` to add a new row and not populate one. What if DB will now return more records?... Then again exception

Comment: I tried but i got the same error

Comment: did you try moving dataGridView1.Rows.Add(); as first statement in while loop...

Answer (score 0):

I Support Khans proposal. Try catching a row from the datareader in a String Array and add this with Datagridview.Rows.Add (myArray); to the grid. So you leave it to the grid to take and assign the values to the next row.

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer. i want to check wheather the row is created first if not create the row. Here is the Code

```
 try
        {
            int i=0;
            double credit=0.00, debit=0.00;
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select accounts,credit,debit from tbl_open_balance where status='A'", con);
            dr=cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while(dr.Read())
            {
                if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count < i + 1) dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value=dr["accounts"].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = dr["credit"].ToString();
                credit = credit + Convert.ToDouble(dr["credit"].ToString());
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = dr["debit"].ToString();
                debit = debit + Convert.ToDouble(dr["debit"].ToString());
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                i++;
            }
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = "Credit";
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = "";
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = credit.ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            i++;
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = "Debit";
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = "";
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = debit.ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            i++;
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = "Total";
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = "";
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = (credit - debit).ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
            dataGridView1.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(238,239,249);
            dataGridView1.CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.SingleHorizontal;
            dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.DarkTurquoise;
            dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
            dataGridView1.BackgroundColor = Color.White;

            dataGridView1.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
            dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersBorderStyle = DataGridViewHeaderBorderStyle.None;
            dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(20, 25, 72);
            dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
            dr.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            dr.Close();
        }
```